# modify href of a tab with CSS

Tags: css

is there any way to modify href attribut of a tab with CSS ?
thanks

Comment: What's a "tab"? Are you perhaps trying to ask if you can change the `href` of an `a` element with CSS? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You are trying to modify HTML with CSS. CSS is for styling only.

If you want to modify HTML look into Javascript. Or if you just want the HTML to change depending on user input look into PHP.